# Benefits of Dagger when using Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I'm starting a new app from scratch and really giving a hard look as to what goes into it. Part of this means using Android Architecture Components and thinking about how ViewModel plays into everything.

For the most part I understand creating custom ViewModel Factories and using that to populate what goes into a given instance.

My question is, if you treat ViewModel Factories as essentially Modules in Dagger, why would I want to use Dagger still ? What are the benefits?

If the ViewModel is supposed to handle state/contexts, why wouldn't I just use factories to create the relevant dependancies and not leave them lingering outside of their given contexts?

edit: is testability the only real answer here? do ViewModel Factories not provide a way to do that?

Comment: Starting from the bottom of your question. 
Yes, testability matters. 
Also, Dagger gives you 2 more benefits: 
1) It enables loose coupling
2) Make your code less boilerplate

Comment: I wasn't implying testability didn't matter, it was more so asking if it was simpler and if there was something stopping you from creating custom ViewModel Factories to give you 1 + 2

Comment: Automatic resolution of dependencies with properly scoped instances.